# while loop until certain condition on the function value is met

Tags: matlab, loops, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit some data with Matlab, using the least square method.

I found best fit parameters, and I want to determine the uncertainty on them now.

To determine the uncertainty on the first parameter, say a, we have seen in  course that one should apply a variation to one parameter, until the difference between the function (evaluated at that variation) minus the original function value equals 1.

That is, I have a vector called `[bestparam]` in my Matlab code, containing the four parameters a, b, c and d.

I also have a function defined in another file, called `chi-square`, which I evaluated at the best parameters.

I now want to apply a small variation to the parameter a, and keep doing this until chi-square(a + variation) - chi-square = 1. The difference must be exactly one. I implemented for this the following code:

```
i = 0;
a_new = a + i;
%small variation on the parameter a
new_param = [a_new b c d];
%my new parameters at which I want the function chisquare to be evaluated
newchisquare = feval(@chisquare, [new_param], X, Y, dY);
%the function value 
while newchisquare - chisquarevalue ~= 1
    i = i + 0.0001;
    a_new = a_new + i;
    new_param = [a_new b c d];
    newchisquare = feval(@chisquare, [new_param], X, Y, dY);
end
disp(a_new);
disp(newchisquare);
```

But when I execute this loop, it never stops running. When I change the condition to `< 1`, i.e. that the difference should be larger than one, then it does stop after like 5 seconds. But then the difference between the function values is no longer exactly one. For example, my original function value is 63.5509 and the new one is then 64.6145 which is not exactly 1 larger.

So is there some way to implement the code, and to keep updating the parameter a until the difference is exactly one? Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Performing numerical methods I wouldn't recommend using operations like `==` or `~=` unless you are sure that you are comparing two integers. Only small deviations of your value may cause your code to never stop. You can apply some tolerance treshold to make your code stop if it is approximately correct:

```
TOL = 1e-2;
while (abs(newchisquare - chisquarevalue) <= 1 - TOL)
    % your code
end
```